# How do I convert inline JS coding into an external style sheet?

Tags: javascript

I have JS code in both the body and head portions of my page. If I wanted to have them be in an external .js file, how would I move them over and then call them back onto the page?

Head -

```
<script language="Javascript">
setInterval("settime()", 1000);

function settime () {
var curtime = new Date();
var curhour = curtime.getHours();
var curmin = curtime.getMinutes();
var cursec = curtime.getSeconds();
var time = "";

if(curhour == 0) curhour = 12;
time = (curhour > 12 ? curhour - 12 : curhour) + ":" +
     (curmin < 10 ? "0" : "") + curmin + ":" +
     (cursec < 10 ? "0" : "") + cursec + " " +
     (curhour > 12 ? "pm" : "am");

document.date.clock.value = time;
}
</script>
```

Body -

```
<script language="JS" type="text/javascript">
var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                       "June", "July", "August", "September",
                       "October", "November", "December");

var today = new Date();
var todayMonth = today.getMonth();
var todayDate = today.getDate();
var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
document.write(monthArray[todayMonth] + " " + todayDate + ", " + todayYear);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your JS code into an external file (say, my.js) and include it within your page as :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>`

Of course, the above assumes that my.js lies in the same folder/directory as your page. you'll need to adjust the `src` value as per the location of you JS file.

Comment: As far as the external .js file goes, do I include everything that is between the <script></script> tags, excluding them?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Ensure that you put all of the script code from both the `head` and `body` portions, since it is possible that you have some overlapping JS code across the two.

Comment: Not really. If you don't have tons of lines of JS code, you should be able to figure it out with a look.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. You've been a great help. Double plus for helping so much :)

Comment: No problems! Looking at your code above, doesn't look like you have duplicate code across the two scripts.